# Set div's height like height of next sibling div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, height, siblings

**EDIT:**  Question shortened

I have two divs next to each other which are siblings. The height of the second div changes when the window is resized for mobile (one line of text within the div breaking into two lines).

Now I want to set the height of the first div according to the height of the second div.

In my case there are the following conditions which I can't rely on:

- the divs only have classes so I can't use getelelementbyid()
- adding table / table-cell to a container and both divs won't work either because the toggle which is for what the divs are for would not open anymore
- I can't make the first div a child of the second div due to the functionality of the toggle

So my guess was to do it with jQuery and I have the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".toggle-info").height($(this).next().outerHeight());
  
});
```

```css
.toggle-info {
  float:right;
  width:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background: green;
}

.toggle-trigger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0; 
  background: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="toggle-info">first div with info-icon</div>
  <div class="toggle-trigger"><a href="#">second div with toggle headline</a></div>
```

This code does not work and I don't know why, can you help me with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a [callback](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height-function) to the height method, inside which `this` will refer to the current `toggle-info` element so you can use `$(this).next().outerHeight()` inside the callback to get the height of the next sibling

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".toggle-info").height(function() {
    return $(this).next().outerHeight()
  });

});
```

```css
.toggle-info {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;<!--To hide overflow content-->
}
.toggle-trigger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0 50px 0 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle-info">first div with info-icon</div>
<div class="toggle-trigger"><a href="#">second div with toggle headline</a></div>
<br />
<div class="toggle-info">first div with info-icon</div>
<div class="toggle-trigger" style="height: 54px;"><a href="#">second div with toggle headline</a></div>
```

Comment: You example works great, thank you! :) Sorry, what I forgot to mention was that there are also toggles inside toggles and for these so-called sub-toggles the code does not work. Do you have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Please can you help me with the second part of my question? ;) I try to find out why the code does not work for sub-toggles inside a top-toggle. All toggles are closed by default on page load. Now when I change the $(document).ready(function()) into a $(window).scroll(function()) it appears that the heights are adapted correctly, also for the sub toggles. It seems to me that somehow the original code for whatever reason does not "reach" the sub-toggles that are hidden on page load, can that be?

Comment: can you share a sample of the html causing the probelm

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wz82kkhb/1/ - edit this fiddle to show your problem

Comment: Thank you. I updated the fiddle and it works but it doesn't on my test site, it only works for the toggles that are visible on page load. When i open those "top" toggles then the sub toggles haven't changed. The thing is when the function is called again after the sub toggles are visible (e.g. on window scroll; tested) then also those styles change. I need to find a way to "reach" all toggles on one function call if my whole assumption is right

Comment: @Thorin after making teh changes you need to click on the update button which will give you an updated url

Comment: @Thorin to offer any kind of help we will have to see the markup so it is better you share the updated fiddle url

Comment: @Thorin whether those inner elements are loaded dynamically in your case.... try to add a console logging to see whether the script is executing for the inner elements.... like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wz82kkhb/10/ - then see the browser console

Comment: Alright thank you! I'm stupid. :) Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Thorin2/wz82kkhb/11/

Comment: Ok thank you I did that. On my site there are now four outer elements ("top toggles" :) ) and this is in the console log after page load: 44, 0, 44, 0, 44, 0, 44. Each number is in a new line. I don't know what these numbers mean but somehow it looks like the script is only executing for the four outer elements, is this right?

Comment: @Thorin it is not a solution, but try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wz82kkhb/12/

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it but it does not work. I replaced the original toggle code from the plugin with your code to test it but none of the toggle infos change height. Here is the js code that is used by the toggle plugin as it is executed on my site: http://jsfiddle.net/Thorin2/wz82kkhb/13/ . I had added an if else statement to scroll to top if a toggle opens. And here is the same code with your code added: http://jsfiddle.net/Thorin2/wz82kkhb/15/ the fiddle works but not on my end and I have no clue :/

Comment: For those who are interested in these comments and would like to know what my result is, here is my workaround: I call the function on window load, window resize and on click of the toggle trigger: $(window).on("load resize",function(e){

  $(".toggle-info").height(function() {
    return $(this).next().outerHeight()
  }); 
  
$('.trigger-top').on('click',function(){

setTimeout(function(){ 

  $(".toggle-info").height(function() {
    return $(this).next().outerHeight()
  });   }, 1);
});

});
 It's not very nice but it does what it's supposed to.